# LDAP query for users and computers in "Domain Computers" group

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to build some LDAP query using PowerShell or C# to search for a certain user or computer in the "Domain Computers" predefined group.

I know that it is not a regular group.

It is possible to separate that query as follows:

For a computer in the "Domain Computers" group:

```
$strFilter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(primaryGroupID=515)(name=MyPC))"
```

For a user in the "Domain Users" group:

```
$strFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(primaryGroupID=515)(name=MyUser))"
```

But I would like to find another query, due to some constrains.

Using Active Directory searcher, I was able to find the "Domain Computers" group under the "Users" OU with the following parameters:

```
distinguishedName = CN=Domain Computers,CN=Users,DC=MyDC,DC=local
objectCategory = CN=Group,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=MyDC,DC=local
objectClass = top ; group
```

I tried to build the query in the following syntax, with no success:

For query a computer:

```
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=computer)(name=MyPC)(CN=Domain computers,CN=Users,DC=supportlab,DC=lcoal))"
```

Any idea how can compose both queries for users and computers, using the above syntax?

Comment: If you use AD Powershell you could simply do Get-ADGroupMember "Groupname"  and it will return any members, regardless the type of object.  IF you want to search for a specific string in the name you could use the following: Get-ADGroupMember TestGroup | where {$_.Name -like "*SomethingImSearching*"}

Comment: What constraints?

Comment: My application tries to query the DC for users and computers twice- one time for "Domain Computers" and second time for "Domain Users". So I would like the query string to be generalized - just to replace the "Domain Computers" string with "Domain Users" and replace the "objectClass=computer" with "objectClass=user"

Comment: Reply for Kage - I'm using C# hard coded string for this query.

Comment: You can combine both queries into one using | (OR) filter and then separate users from computers on client side

Comment: Reply for oldovets - can you please write the exact query in the format of:    "(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=computer)...

Comment: You can combine both queries in a single LDAP query string; e.g.: `(&(|(&(objectClass=computer)(primaryGroupID=515))(&(objectClass=user)(primaryGroupID=513)))(name=foo))`. Is that what you are asking?